# Using RemoteViews to set Visibility of widget button

Tags: android, button, widget, visibility

I've got a widget with one button which I want to display as either Green, Amber or Red - I need to be able to change from one to another programmatically after the widget is loaded. I have tried a huge range off different approaches to this but all I've ever succeeded at is changing the background colour. An approach I am messing with is to have the button on the widget in three versions but make only the one I want visible. Because of the amount of messing about this is taking, I've created a very small app to test just this, leaving the main app alone till I have an answer.

The code below responds to a MainActivity button press:

```
 public void green (View view){

    Context context = this;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);

    RemoteViews views =new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
   views.setInt(R.id.button1, "setVisiblity", VISIBLE);
   views.setInt(R.id.button2, "setVisiblity", GONE);
   views.setInt(R.id.button3, "setVisiblity", GONE);
   views.setInt(R.id.example_widget_button, "setBackgroundColor",android.graphics.Color.RED);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

}
```

I know the button press is working because, if I comment out the Visibility lines, the example button switches to a red background so the widget is being updated, but if I include the visibility lines I get 'Error loading widget'.

Trying to change the colour of this button remotely has become a bit of a saga - I've tried changing background tints and background images but only only seem to be able to change background colour which produces a rather ugly block on the home screen. I has a sad :O(

Answer (score 0):

- Do you try this:

  views.setViewVisibility(R.id.button1, View.GONE);

Comment: Thanks for that Kasim - it shows promise. As you can see, I've got a lot of confusion about the form I should use to pass a command to a remote view - I thought I had to use setInt or setString. Also, Android studio deletes the "View" in "View.GONE" and it still works.

Comment: You're welcome, Using the widget for Android is a little different other components. there is limited use.